# how to cast nvarchar to decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i know how to convert nvarchar to decimal(18,4) Cast method. my tables rows count 80000. My query run perfect below...

```
SELECT  top 80000 id, Cast(MH as decimal(18,4)) as MH 
FROM TaskRelations WHERE MH is not null
```

BUT;

but below select query not WORK! if write below:

```
SELECT   id, Cast(MH as decimal(18,4)) as MH 
FROM TaskRelations WHERE MH is not null
```

ERROR: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: That's because it's impossible to cast one of the MH record not in the first 80000 rows. What is the MH datatype?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have non-numeric data in your `MH` field after row 80,000.

You can use the [`ISNUMERIC` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) but it is notoriously buggy and will give you loads of false positives depending on your data.

Comment: @programmerist - What is that number based on?  Your queries in the original post and your error code indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is usually that indeed some of the nvarchars in the MH columns are not convertible to decimal.

You can try to inspect the data visually, but as you have more than 80k recordsm, that might not be feasible. Try to inspect the data in some other way - you can use `isNumeric`, or use `group by` on the first (or last) three characters of the column, to find the erring data.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error your receiving is due to the fact that some record past the top 80000 records cannot be converted to decimal.  Check your data on all rows > 80000

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT   max(MH) as max_mh, min(mh) as min_mh
FROM TaskRelations 
WHERE MH is not null
```

the non-numeric values should be lower or higher than the numeric ones.